# SetTimeout não funcionando, o que tem de errado?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

eu preciso que essa janela só abra após 3 segundos, mas não estou conseguindo, colocando o setTimeout direto no botão. O que tem de errado?
:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin() {
    var divText = document.getElementById("div-janela").outerHTML;
    var myWindow = window.open('', '',);
    var doc = myWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(divText);
    doc.close();
}
</script>
<div id="div-janela">conteudo da div</div>
<input type="submit" onclick="setTimeout(openWin(), 3000)" value="abrir janela">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu alterei e coloquei o timeout dentro da função openWin, e funcionou normalmente.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin() {
    setTimeout(function(){
  var divText = document.getElementById("div-janela").outerHTML;
  var myWindow = window.open('', '',);
  var doc = myWindow.document;
  doc.open();
  doc.write(divText);
  doc.close();
 },3000);
    
}
</script>
<div id="div-janela">conteudo da div</div>
<input type="submit" onclick="openWin()" value="abrir janela">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function openWin() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      var divText = document.getElementById("div-janela").textContent = "Abriu :D";
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="div-janela">conteudo da div</div>

<input type="submit" onclick="openWin()" value="abrir janela">
```

Você poderia usar [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/IIFE), dentro da tag HTML

```js
console.log("Ignore o erro");
```

```html
<h1 onclick="(setTimeout(function(){alert('acho :D');}, 1000))()">Clique</h1>
```

## O problema...

Quando o usuário clica, ele(`onClick()`) chama o `openWind()` imediatamente, o que acontece é que vocẽ não pode colocar `openWin()` dentro do `setTimeout()` você tem que remover os parenteses, ficaria algo como isso...

```
<div id="div-janela">conteudo da div</div>
<input type="submit" onclick="setTimeout(openWin, 3000)" value="abrir janela">

<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin() {
  var divText = document.getElementById("div-janela").outerHTML;
  var myWindow = window.open('', '',);
  var doc = myWindow.document;
  doc.open();
  doc.write(divText);
  doc.close();
}
</script>
```

Passando `openWin` sem os parenteses. O `setTimeout()` receberá o que tem que ser feito e só depois executará a função.

Comment: Perfeito! :D mt obrigado!!

Comment: Droga, na verdade não deu certo.. eu preciso levar o conteúdo da div para essa janela. tentei assim: function openWin() {
    setTimeout(function(){var divText = document.getElementById("div-janela").outerHTML;
    var myWindow = window.open('', '',);
    var doc = myWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(divText);
    doc.close();}, 3000);
} não funcionou..

Comment: Atualizei, minha resposta não está errada, você deve ter implementado errado, pois aqui eu não fiz o seu trabalho, só te passei a noção de como voce deveria fazer, mas na resposta te explico o que voce fez de errado(na pergunta).